# Add ssl to rest api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, rest

I have an express js application running on aws ec2 instance that acts as rest api for my application. If i want to add ssl certification for my expressjs api what should i do?

1)Do i need to get a domain with ssl certification and map it to my ec2 ip address?
2)Or its enough to put aws API gateway in front of my ec2 instance , use the free ssl from ACM and get a domain without ssl?
3)Or get a domain with ssl and also ssl in acm?

(kind of confused with understanding domain and ssl, any help would be appreciated)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The default pattern for this kind of use case, assuming that you don't want to manage a domain + certificate, is to put your EC2 instance behind a service that integrates with ACM, such as Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) or an Amazon CloudFront distribution.

API Gateway, while also giving you an SSL certificate, would also bring many other features that you'd still have to pay for.

[Example](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-acm-certificates-ec2/)

EDIT:
Original question was not formatted properly and I missed option 3).

If you are going to get a domain, then you have other options such as managing it with Route53 and directing your traffic to the EC2, or do the same but with the domain registrar. This assumes that the EC2 has a static IP address that allows you to address it. At this point, you can get an SSL Cert either via AWS ACM or by other means directly on the EC2 (i.e. [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)). The difference between the two, aside from price, would be that one requires you to manage your own certificate while the other is an AWS managed service.

Comment: So I can put my ec2 behind the cloudfront and buy a domain

Comment: See my edit, I didn't see option #3 in your question.